# Virtual machine network issue with host and ping service checks (within Nagios Core and from command line)

Tags: kvm-virtualization, nagios, ping, libvirt

I have got a Ubuntu server guest virtual machine (installed via `virt-install`) which runs Nagios Core monitoring but there is a major issue with the monitoring  (i.e. ping packet loss / RTA or connection time outs indicated intermittently in the Nagios web interface).

I am monitoring 19 hosts (UP/DOWN) and ping service only with default intervals/rechecks etc.

The Ubuntu server VM has 1 CPU (default settings), 5GB storage and 1 GB memory (there is plenty resource free) but uses all the default virt-install network settings*.

There are a number of other (Debian) guest VMs on the VM host.

`ping` (from command line) is slightly slower on this VM and sometimes hangs for several seconds (this doesn't happen on other VMs).

*EDIT: I thought it may be a network interface issue so changed it to use `virtio` (in VM XML interface configuration) but even after that the problem persists.

It seems to be a network (config) issue on this particular VM.

PING INVESTIGATION:

1. From this Ubuntu guest VM with network issue:

```
--- X.X.X.X ping statistics ---
100 packets transmitted, 63 received, 37% packet loss, time 101341ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.352/0.491/0.637/0.056 ms
```

2. From another (Debian) guest VM:

```
--- X.X.X.X ping statistics ---
100 packets transmitted, 100 received, 0% packet loss, time 101371ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.278/0.386/0.505/0.056 ms
```

Ping from the problem guest VM to the other guest VM:

```
--- X.X.X.X ping statistics ---
100 packets transmitted, 100 received, 0% packet loss, time 101354ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.345/0.531/0.798/0.092 ms
```

There is no apparent IP conflict either.

Comment: Are you sure whether that is a Nagios problem? Maybe there is a networking problem, and Nagios is correctly reporting that.

Comment: Yes i don't think it's nessicarily a Nagios problem. I'm wondering if it's the default virt-install network provision plus the fact there are other VM on the host...

Comment: Then do the check operation (e.g. send a ping) "manually" (often enough for a solid statement) and see what happens.

Comment: I've added some more detail. Thanks.

Comment: So not Nagios-related. You should make sure that there is no IP conflict. Take the problem VM offline and try to ping its IP afterwards (after flushing the ARP cache). In addition: What happens if the other VM pings the problem VM?